# Why do react components as class must have `render` method, while those as functions don't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I write a component as class, it needs the `render` method. For example:

```
class Greet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
  }
}
```

As a result, `render()` is a method of every `Greet` instance. Meanwhile, if I write the same component as a factory function, the `render()` method isn't required:

```
function Greet() {
  return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
}
```

In both cases, to render that component in the browser window, it's needed to run this:

```
ReactDOM.render({ 
  <Greet />,
  document.getElementById("root")
});
```

So, how come that when a `class` is passed as a parameter to `ReactDOM.render()`, it needs `render()` to be included, while a function doesn't?

Is it, by any chance, because the `class` can't directly return something without encapsulating it in a method, so it was decided for that method to have the same name? In that case, how does the `ReactDOM.render()` work in the each scenario?

Answer (score 1):

In React think of a functional component as been the render part of a class. A lot of times, especially when using composition, that's often all a React component needs to do.  So this really does cut down on a lot of boiler plate.

But then that leaves a big hole, like how you handle lifecycle / effect methods etc, and that's were Hooks come in.

So then back to your question =>  needs render() to be included

You are kind of correct, if you mean a class (constructor) can't return something, well it can, but it's not advised to do so.  And since in React render can be called multiple times, it certainly wound't make sense for it to be in the constructor anyway.

So in a nutshell, since a functional React component is the render stage, it of course doesn't require a render function.  But since a class constructor shouldn't be used for a render function, it will of course need a render method..